# SQL SubQuery merge

Tags: sql

I have a sql query that looks like

```
Select count(A), B,C,D,E
from
(   )alias
group by B,C,D,E
```

Here column E is a date. I want another column that will give me the number of days between date E and today (I have to fetch system date from another table)

```
select date(sysdate) from table1
```

and I will be using `DATEDIFF()` function to find the difference between column E and system_date
Any idea how I combine the two ?
Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Which dbms? (datediff, sysdate etc are product specific...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can use CURDATE() also instead of NOW()

```
SELECT count(A),B,C,D,E,DATEDIFF(NOW(),E) AS Days
FROM table
GROUP BY B,C,D,E;
```

Days will list the number of days between values in E and today.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select tab.*, datadif( tab.e ,tab2.f) difference 
from (Select count(A), B,C,D,E 
      from (   )alias
      group by B,C,D,E) tab1,
     (select date(sysdate) f 
      from table1) tab2
```